# Table added to MYSQL, but returning 500 on post

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, knex.js

I am using the Node module KNEX to make MYSQL calls. I want users to be able to add their own custom tables. I am able to add a database to MYSQL with all the columns, but in my console I get an 500 internal server error.

This is my custom file knex.js which access the MYSQL database:

```
knex.js

var knex = require('knex')({
    client: 'mysql',
    connection: {
        host: 'localhost',
        user: USER,
        password: PASSWORD,
        database: 'tasks'
    }
});

exports.createUserTable = function(x){
    console.log(x);
    knex.schema.hasTable(x.id).then(function(exists) {
        if (!exists) {
            return knex.schema.createTable(x.id, function(t){
                t.increments();
                t.string(x.type, 50);
                for (var y in x.val){
                    t.string(x.val[y], 255);
                }
                t.timestamps();
            });
        } else {
            return console.log("Error!");
        }
    });     
};
```

As I mentioned before, the database gets created so this function seems to work fine. This next bit of code receives a post request from angular.js. The data gets compiled into a var called **table** and **table** is sent to knex.createUserTable(). However, no values show up in the console and I am returned with a 500 error:

```
tables.js

router.route('/addTable')
    .post(function(req, res){

    //code above omitted
        var knx = knex.createUserTable(table);

        knx.then(function(c) {
            console.log(c);
        }).catch(function(err){
            console.log("Error: " + err);
        }).done(function(){
            console.log("Mission accomplished!");
            res.status(200).end();      
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer. The outer most function should be returned as well.

```
   return knex.schema.hasTable(x.id).then(function(exists) {
       if (!exists) {
            return knex.schema.createTable(x.id, function(t){
                t.increments();
                t.string(x.type, 50);
                for (var y in x.val){
                    t.string(x.val[y], 255);
                }
                t.timestamps();
            });
        } else {
            return console.log("Error!");
        }
    });
```